# svn checkout with ssh tunnel on fedora missing ssh-askpass library

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, svn, tunnel

I'm running fedora 20 and when I try to run `svn checkout svn+ssh://repo` I get this error after typing my ssh passphrase for my key:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib64/misc/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

I have installed openssh-askpass using yum and it did not create the file `/usr/lib64/misc/ssh-askpass`.  What could I be doing wrong?

My `.subversion/config` file:

```
[tunnels]
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -p 9001
```

inside .bashrc:

```
export SVN_SSH="ssh -AT server ssh -T";
```

Setting my output to verbose I get the following.  (the url of the server has been changed)

```
username@username-VirtualBox:~/dev$ svn checkout svn+ssh://server/trunk upe_trunk
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/username/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for server
debug1: /home/username/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server [196.22.96.105] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/dsa.key type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/dsa.key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p1-hpn14v4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p1-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 7e:5c:4c:f1:0b:28:da:db:5b:29:60:6b:ab:16:f3:14
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/dsa.key
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/dsa.key': 
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server ([192.22.96.105]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 7e:5c:4c:f1:0b:28:da:db:5b:29:60:6b:ab:16:f3:14
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: set_newkeys: rekeying
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: set_newkeys: rekeying
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: ssh -T server svnserve -t
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib64/misc/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 5176, received 4424 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13314.9, received 11380.5
debug1: Exit status 255
svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://server/var/svn/repo/upe/trunk'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was in my environment variable SVN_SSH.  I don't understand why but by changing it to:

```
export SVN_SSH="ssh -T";
```

it worked.